# Problem with criteria in C# LINQ query 3-way join

Tags: c#, linq, join

I need to run a LINQ query, doing a 3-way inner join where all 3 tables link to the other 2. However, I'm having trouble getting the syntax right for the join criteria. If I were to write it in SQL, it would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM [Table1]
JOIN [Table2]
    ON [Table1_Id] = [Table2_T1_Id]
JOIN [Table3]
    ON [Table1_Type_Id] = [Table3_Type_Id]
    AND [Table2_Value_Id] = [Table3_Value_Id]
WHERE [Table1_Id] IN idsList
ORDER BY[Table1_Id], [Table2_Id];
```

Running this right in the database works correctly. But when I tried to write it in LINQ format as follows:

```
var results = from a in context.TableA
            join b in context.TableB
            on a.TableA_Id equals b.TableB_TA_Id into ab
            join c in context.TableC
            on new { a.TableA_Type_Id, ab.TableB_Value_Id }        <-- Errors point to this line
            equals { c.TableC_Type_Id, c.TableC_Value_Id } into abc
            where idsList.Contains(abc.TableA_Id)
            select new
            {
              // various values to retrieve listed here
            };
```

I get the following 'CS1061' errors (referencing the line indicated above):

```
'IEnumerable<TableB>' does not contain a definition for 'TableB_Value_Id' and no accessible extension
    method 'TableB_Value_Id' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<TableB>' could be found
    (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

If I change the problematic line to read as follows:

```
on new { a.TableA_Type_Id, b.TableB_Value_Id }
```

I get this error instead:

```
The name 'b' does not exist in the current context
```

I also preceded the criteria with 'labels?' (I'm not sure what to call them) 'j' and 'k' like this:

```
on new { j = a.TableA_Type_Id, k = b.TableB_Value_Id }
equals { j = c.TableC_Type_Id, k = c.TableC_Value_Id } into abc
```

and tried it both ways (as described above), but this made absolutely no difference. What am I missing?

**Edit -- SOLUTION FOUND:**

I forgot to mention in my first post that my original code did not have the "into xx" clauses and I was seeing different error messages. In trying to resolve them, I added the "into xx" clauses and all but one error went away. Thanks' to Yong Shun's answer, I removed the "into xx" clauses and tried it with the "labels", and this finally worked:

```
var results = from a in context.TableA
            join b in context.TableB
            on a.TableA_Id equals b.TableB_TA_Id
            join c in context.TableC
            on new { j = a.TableA_Type_Id, k = b.TableB_Value_Id }
            equals new { j = c.TableC_Type_Id, k = c.TableC_Value_Id }
            where idsList.Contains(a.TableA_Id)
            select new
            {
              // various values to retrieve listed here
            };
```

Thanks Yong Shun!

Answer (score 1):

In LINQ, we normally use join ... into (with `.DefaultIfEmpty()`) to perform the LEFT JOIN operation.

From your query, you are performing the INNER JOIN.

Hence, your LINQ query expression should be as below:

```cs
var results = from a in context.TableA
            join b in context.TableB
            on a.TableA_Id equals b.TableB_TA_Id
            join c in context.TableC
            on new { a.TableA_Type_Id, b.TableB_Value_Id }
            equals new { c.TableC_Type_Id, c.TableC_Value_Id }
            where idsList.Contains(a.TableA_Id)
            select new
            {
              // various values to retreive listed here
            };
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that that's the way I had it, and I had different errors and I was trying to figure them out. It turns out that the solution was a combination I hadn't tried, but your answer made me try putting the "labels" (for lack a better term) in front of the parameters.